# wso2 enterprise mobile manager

Tags: tomcat7, wso2, jaggery-js

I'm trying to install wso2 EMM 1.

But I'm not able to start server itself. It gave me an error for database not started or not configured. Everything done as per instruction.

```
TID: [0] [EMM] [2014-03-16 12:15:11,685]  INFO {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.app.mgt.TomcatJaggeryWebappsDeployer} -  Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/assets].File[D:\wso2mobileserver-1.0.0\wso2mobileserver-1.0.0\bin\..\repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\assets] {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.app.mgt.TomcatJaggeryWebappsDeployer}`

TID: [0] [EMM] [2014-03-16 12:15:12,014] ERROR {JAGGERY.config.app:js} -   {JAGGERY.config.app:js}
TID: [0] [EMM] [2014-03-16 12:15:12,014] ERROR {JAGGERY.config.app:js} -   {JAGGERY.config.app:js}
TID: [0] [EMM] [2014-03-16 12:15:12,014] ERROR {JAGGERY.config.app:js} -  Database is not configured or has not started up {JAGGERY.config.app:js}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to follow [these](https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM100/General+Server+Configurations) steps to configure the MySql database. It seems you have either not configured the database or the database server is down. Make sure you download and install the mysql connector jar and add the db configurations properly as per the doc. Also check whether you have properly restored the database script.